# Where is Tomcat Console Output on Windows

Tags: windows, tomcat, logging

I used to start tomcat from its bin folder with the startup.bat. By running that script it opened a java window in which I can see the outputs from tomcat. However, I've been told that this is not the right way to start tomcat on a windows server. Therefore I start tomcat now over the service program. By doing so no java window is being opened anymore and therefore I can't see the output msg from tomcat.

I have also looked into the logs folder of tomcat. Those saved outputs are not the same as the one I had/have in java window. Does anyone know where I can find those outputs?

Many thanks in advance for any advices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we assume your install is in C:\program files\apache software foundation\apache-tomcat{ver}\

then it is inside, in the log directory, in a file catalina.out.

> C:\program files\apache software
>   foundation\apache-tomcat{ver}\logs\catalina.out

It's worth to note the name of the file depends on your configuration, also the name of the logs directory can be different depending on configuration but I assume you preserved default config.

Comment: There I have for example a file catalina.2011-12-02.log. But this does not contain the same information as the java output window...

Comment: Is it possible that besides the catalina.2011-12-02.log you have files that are named localhost{foo}.log and manager{foo}.log? I am pretty sure the combination of those files would be exactly what you would normally see in your java console, unless your tomcat is configured otherwise.

Comment: The problem was that Tomcat didn't have the rights to write all the logs in the User's folder. I changed that  and now I can also see stout log files.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows (I am using Windows 10) you should do these to check the running application's logs:-

1. Install Notepad++
2. Open C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat {ver}\logs\tomcat{ver}-stdout.{date}.log in Notepad++
3. Open View menu and enable 'Monitoring' in Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

Usually the logs should be in $TOMCAT_HOME/logs

When running tomcat as a service, i have noticed that Tomcat sometimes generated logs in the folder where tomcat was started from so also check $TOMCAT_HOME/bin for any possible log files.

This is why you should configure Log4j so that you have control of where the log files are created.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing. There is no catalina.out on MS Windows. On MS there is catalina-datetime-in-some-random-format.log but that is **NOT** catalina.out nor does it contain same information.

On a real operating systems there is catalina.out that contains all output from JVM both stdout and stderr. On MS windoh! ;) it is just a log file for Tomcat JUL log file (not CONSOLE/stdout/stderr). Then there are catalina-stdout.log and catalina-stderr.log files. 
So every single time you need to find some information on M$ you have dig through all three files. Most of contain duplicate information making it absolute hell to try to process the logs via any automation like ELK stack.