# Java, how could we log and store it into local file, a stateless session bean?

Tags: java, string, file, ejb, try-catch

I am trying to log the program's execution flow to better understand how servlets, EJBs and JSPs work together.
Currently the difficulty I am facing is to output the log to a local file.

I have first tried with the Java logger API, studying this example:

Using Java log API:

http://wiki4.caucho.com/Java_EE_Servlet/JSP_tutorial_:_Adding_an_error_page,_logging,_and_other_forms_of_debugging#Using_Java_log_API

And I have written:

```
package beans;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;


@Stateless
public class ComentarioNota {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ComentarioNota.class.getName());

    public String convierteComentarioNota(String evaluacion, String comentario) {

            log.logp(Level.WARNING,
            this.getClass().getName(),
            this.getClass().getName(), this.getClass().getName() + "::convierteComentarioNota::el usuario introdujo: " + evaluacion + comentario);


            if (evaluacion.trim().equals("Apto") && comentario != null && comentario.length() > 5) {
                return "Apto";
            } else {
                return "No Apto";
            }

}
```

And it indeed outputs the log with ClassName::ClassMethod::User input info.

**However it outputs the log info to the console, I need it in a local file, how could we log into a local file?**

I have tried to use the PrintWriter and creating a new file with its contents:

```
package beans;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;


@Stateless
public class ComentarioNota {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ComentarioNota.class.getName());

    public String convierteComentarioNota(String evaluacion, String comentario) {
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("log.txt")) {


            out.println(this.getClass().getName() + "::convierteComentarioNota::el usuario introdujo: " + evaluacion + comentario);

            if (evaluacion.trim().equals("Apto") && comentario != null && comentario.length() > 5) {
                return "Apto";
            } else {
                return "No Apto";
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ComentarioNota.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return "No Apto";
    }
}
```

However this does not create a new file.

**How could we create that new local file and send the log output to it?**

Thank you for your help!.

I have also read:
[How do I save a String to a text file using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053467/how-do-i-save-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-java)

[Where does the ServletContext.log messages go in tomcat 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31063812/where-does-the-servletcontext-log-messages-go-in-tomcat-7)

EDIT: I have read the comment's tutorial: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/handlers.html#streamhandler

ANd I have found that we can add handlers to the logger, and there is a built in handler which is FileHandler which is supposed to create one file with the log's contents. I have tried the following:

```
package beans;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;


@Stateless
public class ComentarioNota {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ComentarioNota.class.getName());

    public String convierteComentarioNota(String evaluacion, String comentario) {

        try {
            FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("comentarioNota.txt");
            log.addHandler(handler);

            log.logp(Level.WARNING,
                    this.getClass().getName(),
                    "convierteComentarioNota", this.getClass().getName() + "::convierteComentarioNota::el usuario introdujo: " + evaluacion + comentario);

            if (evaluacion.trim().equals("Apto") && comentario != null && comentario.length() > 5) {
                return "Apto";
            } else {
                return "No Apto";
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ComentarioNota.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ComentarioNota.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return "No Apto";
    }
}
```

However I still seeing the log being outputted to the console and no file is being created:

[image]

And no file is being creted because at least it does not show up in the IDE and I have also try to find it:

[image]

***Could you help me figuring out how to log to a local file properly?***

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure java.util.logging. what you're looking for is the FileHandler. I actually prefer other logging APIs but for your purposes please start here: [Tutorial: Java Logging Configuration](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/configuration.html)