# Tomcat Server is not Startting in the Window 10:

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I added jenkins.war file under `C:\tomcat\webapps` directory and trying to start Tomcat server however when I try to make .sh file executable then I am getting following error:

Step1. I entered this command `chmod +x *.sh` in my window `C:\tomcat\bin` directory using command prompt and Command prompt throw this error: 'chmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Step2 I try to run `chmod +x *.sh` command in the Git bash in my window `C:\tomcat\bin` directory and it doesn't show any message

Step3 now I when run ./startup.sh command in the git bash then it show following message:
[image]

Step4 when I enter localhost:8080 in the my browser then browser show me following error message:
[image]

I am not sure why tomcat server is not starting.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to start the tomcat server that Jenkins is running on? Or a separate tomcat instance?

Comment: Hi, I added jenkins.war file under this directory: C:\tomcat\webapps\jenkins.war  and now I am trying to start the tomcat server but no luck.

Comment: Can you check the tomcat logs as [directed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8362343/2344348) and add the output of your catalina.out to your question please. Note that the path they give may be different, but the directory and file should exist.

Comment: Hi, I did not find C:\program files\apache software foundation\apache-tomcat{ver}\logs\catalina.out    path in my program file.  And just letting you know that I downloaded Tomcat from this url http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi and downloaded 3rd option under CORE. Just let me know that I downloaded correct tomcat for window?

Comment: Where did you install TomCat? It should be there - as I mentioned the path may vary, but the logs\catalina.out path will exist in your tomcat installation

Comment: I downloaded tomcat under this directory ==> C:\tomcat

Comment: here is is the log: /c/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: line 434: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102/bin/java: No such file or directory

Comment: catalina.sh is not what you are looking for. it is `catalina.log`

Comment: I found catalina.out file and this is the log I found from "C:\tomcat\logs\catalina.out" ==> "/c/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: line 434: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102/bin/java: No such file or directory"          And I did not find any log file with name catalina.log  and in the suggested link you provided in that they mentioned catalina.out

Comment: Ah okay, does `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102/bin/java` exist? There is nothing after the word 'directory'?

Comment: This is what is display in the directory==> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe  and under C:\Program Files\Java only jdk1.8.0_102 folder display

Comment: Based on that your JRE home is set incorrectly, I believe startup.sh contains this variable - set it to your correct JRE location

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146967/discussion-between-curious-and-peter-reid).

Comment: hi Just letting you know that after settin JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_131 and system restart helped me to successfully starting the Tomcat Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on discussion with you and after you following up on my suggestions.

Solution:

Set JAVA_HOME to correct location in Windows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_131
```